# How to get different data from different device in one UART interrupt callback function at the same time using stm32cubeide?

Tags: embedded, interrupt, uart, stm32f7

I am Interfacing UART based RF module DTDS-622 with STM32F767ZIT6. And I want to receive different data from different RF Module DTDS-622 at the same time . I am able to receive the data from one DTDS-622 module in interrupt mode but when i want to receive the different  data from Different RF DTDS-622 module at the same time , it is not receiving properly

I have tried to receive the data in one call back function. I want to receive the data in one callback function at the same time.

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more information about how everything is connected up. I'm not sure it makes sense to "receive the data in one callback function at the same time". What if only one module has sent something, and the other has not?